# Inequality about matrix quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

Consider a vector $x \in \Bbb R^n$ and two positive definite matrices $A, B \in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$ satisfying a linear matrix inequality $A - B > 0$. Can we draw the conclusion that $x^\top Ax > x^\top Bx$? If not, when $A$ is an identity matrix, can we draw the conclusion that  $x^\top x > x^\top Bx$?

Comment: How do you define $A>B$?

Comment: Sorry, it should be the matrix $A$ and $B$ satisfy a linear matrix inequality $A-B>0$.

Comment: I think what you had written was correct (at least it is common math notation); my question was more to do with the fact that my definition of $A>B$ is exactly the inequality you want happening, since it's the same as $A-B>0$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie  and my question might be a little silly.  I am just wondering  whether can we compare two quadratic form by comparing two positive definite matrix $A$ and $B$. Did you mean the conclusion in my question is correct?

Comment: I would write $A -  B \succ 0$, using `\succ` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A>0$ means $x^TAx>0$ for all non zero $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Now $A-B>0$ implies $x^T(A-B)x>0$ for all non zero $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore, $x^TAx-x^TBx>0$ and the required argument follows.

---

If you consider $A=I$, then $x^Tx> x^TBx$. One thing you can say that $I-B$ is invertible as $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $B$. Because if $1$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ then there exists $x\neq 0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Bx=x$. Therefore we get $x^Tx= x^TBx$.